# Check for file existence before Spring controller runs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application. The set up is like many common applications:

- Database connection configuration is defined in `context.xml` with `<bean id="dataSource" ... >` ...
  via `@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")` for my class `ApplicationConfig` (with `@Configuration`)
- The `dataSource` is then used in `context.xml` to initiate `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

  ```
    <bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
  ```
- My controller classes are typically annotated with `@Controller` and then `@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")` for the methods (which return a String for the jsp file name)
- With MVC pattern, my controller classes have `@Autowired` different service classes; and the service classes `@Autowired` different DAO classes. My DAO classes `@Autowired` `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` for accessing the database.
- In my web.xml, I have `error-page`'s defined, e.g.

  ```
   <web-app ... >
     <error-page>
       <error-code>405</error-code>
       <location>/405ErrorPage.jsp</location>
     </error-page>
       other error pages etc...
   </web-app>
  ```
- My application is packaged into WAR and deployed with Tomcat's manager

This works fine in general, however, I want to add a way to check the existence of a file (possibly a HTML file) and then interrupt the normal flow of how controllers return. So in practice: when there is ongoing maintenance work for database, the database connection of the application will fail and my controllers will return the error page by default. I want to add a way to check for a file ("maintenance-notice.html" for sample) outside the deploy WAR in the server's file system. If the file exists, all the controllers should return the content of the "maintenance-notice.html".

I appreciate the 'magic' of Spring MVC, but at the moment, when the database connection is down, the application will also fail. The controllers returns the error page instead of running anything inside the controller method.

How should I tackle the problem if I want to make all controllers to check for the existence of the file before returning the error page as defined in `web.xml`? Should I add some sort of exception catching at the start of each controller just to check if the database connection is down?

P.S. Perhaps this is another question: What would be the recommended/appropriate way to check for file existence and read the file outside the WAR with Spring's way of doing things?

Sorry, I am not very familiar with the anatomy of Spring MVC, so please bear with me and explain things in smaller steps. Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Advices are the way to go. This way you can intercept in- and outgoing data, perform some computation and modify the returning result. But be aware this is a blocking task.